# Specific IDE, for specific things

Tags: java, python, ide, editor

I need an IDE that can do the following:

- Run on an oldish laptop (2GB Ram, 1.9 ghz intel celeron M)
- Run well on an oldish laptop (with a browswer open)
- Be able to run on windows
- Be able to run smoothly on windows
- Is able to do Java (or, if you really can't find anything, C# will be okay)
- An extension or something for Python would be nice
- Django support would be awesome
- It would be great to have SFTP/FTP editing support that actually works

I don't care about lots of extensibility or commercial support or a kitchen sink or any of that, I just need it to be stable and all of the above.

And, Vim or EMACS aren't answers since they (in my mind, without excessive configuration) don't qualify as IDEs.

And, if this doesn't belong here, please tell me.

EDIT: Code completion is also important.

Comment: Is there any IDE that programmers don't wind up configuring excessively?

Comment: emacs is not an acronym.

Comment: I thought it was something like EMACS Makes A Computer Slow :-)

Comment: FWIW, try vim.  If you don't prefer it for your own reasons, that's fine (who can have a problem with that?), but it does meet your stated requirements, including running smoothly with a small footprint (seems to be your main requirement), code completion (see both omni-completion and older style completion), and SFTP/FTP (see ":help netrw").  (I don't know about special Django support beyond what's needed for any Python code; I don't use Django.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PyDev plugin](http://pydev.org/) gives you Java, Python and Django. Not sure about SFTP/FTP editing.

Comment: Wouldn't run smoothly on a Windows lappie with 2GB RAM, especially with a browser open.

Comment: It runs quite smoothly on my 1.83GHz and 2GB RAM laptop. With firefox open. Though I usually only have several tabs (< 10) open at once.

Comment: Wait... On second thought, the processor that I have is dual core. What about yours?

Comment: Eclipse does have the [Target Management project](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) to handle SSH and FTP connections.

Comment: Hery: My processor is not dual core. There is about a 0.1% chance it will handle Eclipse.

Comment: I have even older laptop with single core processor and Eclipse is not a problem even with Firefox running. And both run from flash drive! But I have to admit that I use Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary + PyDev only, Java support is stripped out.

Comment: I ended up using eclipse. Back to where I started :)

Answer (score 5):

notepad++ has an ftp plugin that works very nicely and runs on very little resource. Will syntax highlight most languages and has some compiler support.

Comment: I doubt it, but come on, how much can you expect from a light-weight solution?

Comment: Yes. It is not enabled by default though. Also the FTP plugin is included with the standard distribution.

Comment: Thanks A LOT. Got ftp working, and I love it. Also, code completion is rudimentary, but works very well. I just wish it had better compiler support, but, I can't get everything :)

Comment: Sorry, notepad++ just doesn't have enough documentation and extensions. Not a full featured IDE.

Answer (score 1):

[E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I think [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is pretty nice now.

Comment: I did read the whole question. I suppose we disagree on what lightweight means. Its definitley more lightweight that eclipse or netbeans in my experience

Comment: The question isn't of more or less lightweight, if you think it will run on a single core, 1.9 Ghz 2 GB ram machine, then I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has support for *Java* and *C#*, does *SFTP/FTP* editing, is scriptable in *Python* and should run fine on a lower end Windows box off that size.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IDE and tools that makes you the most productive.
Use the IDE and tools that you want to use.
Use the IDE and tools that you will enjoy using.

If your computer is preventing you from doing that, then get a new computer.

Long gone are the days when labor was cheap, and hardware expensive.
These days hardware is cheap, labor is expensive.

Your time is worth money. Don't waste it.
You are more important than that.

Whether it's from not being able to use the best tool for the job, or losing time on slow compiles, it all adds up.

In a completely contrived example:
If you're losing 1 hour of productivity a day, 5 days a week, for 48 weeks out of the year, that adds up to 240 hours. Even if you were working minimum wage, at say $10/hour, that's $2400 in lost productivity.

Take whatever you are losing in productivity, and re-invest it into solutions to those problems.